# Creating full screen plots in bokeh

Tags: python, plot, fullscreen, bokeh

I am using bokeh to generate several line plots which are fairly wide in nature. I have been looking but have not found any code that would allow me to initialize the plots so that they took up the full screen size instead of the default box. Here is an example of what I am searching for:

[image: original] vs [image: desired]

Answer (score 0):

This would currently (as of version 0.8.1) require a very small bit of custom JS to make work. I would be happy to help you try and work up the right solution, but I would suggest the Bokeh mailing list, or an issue on the Bokeh GitHub issue tracker would be a more appropriate place for a "back and forth" technical discussion (we should post the final answer here once it is done). Ideally such work could lead to a Pull Request to add this feature to Bokeh itself.

Comment: Did anything ever come of this?

Comment: Bokeh supports more layout options, including some different responsive modes now, but no one has ever made a "full screen" tool (or if they have, then they have not shared it publicly). It's now probably possible to write this as a custom extension to Bokeh, which, given the variety of situations and other JS libs that Bokeh might be used with, might make more sense than trying to make a one-size-fits-all tool. Feel free to drop by the mailing list if you'd like to discuss further.

Comment: Any update 3 years after? (before I reinvent the wheel)